# CXF + polymorphic POST data

Tags: java, json, cxf

My project has a Core and it is extended by projects.

Project classes can extend entities and add data to them. The core supposed to support subclasses in the REST API, but I get exception for not recognizing the added fields.

for example:

**CORE:**

```
Class Student {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
}


Interface StudentServices {
    @Path("/")
    @PUT
    public void saveStudent(Student student);
}
```

And there is an implementation that handles the save operation.
It works well.

But I also want to provide the ability to extend the Student class, which some projects will do and other won't:

**PROJECT:**

```
Class StudentExt extends Student {
   private String extraData;
}
```

If I send the StudentExt in the JSON to the server, the system crushes with an unknown property exception. I don't think disabling the validation will suffice - CXF still wont know that I want to get the extended class.

I also tried Generics but it didn't work:

```
public <T extends Student> void saveStudent(T student);
```

Please help me.
Regards, id